# How to return to multiple columns and restirct rows

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas I got a function takes the value of one column and returns its result to two columns. Now I want to also restrict the rows that are used / the results are returned to. I know I can return to multiple columns like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['foo bar', 'bar foo', 'foo foo', 'bar baz'], 
                 'b': ['']*4, 
                 'c': ['']*4})

def func(text):
    return pd.Series(text.split(' ', maxsplit=1))

df[['b', 'c']] = df.a.apply(func)
```

If I had a function that returns only to a single column this works:

```
df.loc[:2, 'b'] = df.loc[:2, 'a'].apply(lambda x: x+' baz')
```

However if I combine both approaches, only `np.NaN` is produced in the respective cells, as you can see from this piece of code.

```
df.loc[:2, ['b', 'c']] = df.loc[:2, 'a'].apply(func)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need adding `to_numpy()` to remove the index and column different impact, both `Dataframe` and `Series` are index sensitive, so if the index or col mismatch the output will return NaN

```
df.loc[:2, ['b', 'c']] = df.loc[:2, 'a'].apply(func).to_numpy()
df
Out[227]: 
         a    b    c
0  foo bar  foo  bar
1  bar foo  bar  foo
2  foo foo  foo  foo
3  bar baz
```

Check your output

```
df.loc[:2, 'a'].apply(func)
Out[228]: 
     0    1
0  foo  bar
1  bar  foo
2  foo  foo
```

`columns` are [0, 1] not ['b', 'c'] which will make the assign fail

Comment: Thank you that worked. Thanks for also explaining why my approach failed. Very much appreciated.